# AVI Capture in VirtualDub: MP3 Compression

Tags: codec, compression, video-capture, virtualdub, avi

I would like to capture my old VHS tapes to my HDD. I already was successful installing the xvid codec which gives me an acceptable video compression.

But somehow I am not able to set audio compression. In the VirtualDub `Audio` menu I can choose compression. It then shows me a list of available codecs, among them I can select `MPEG Layer-3`. But when I go back to check the settings it is not selected anymore and it definitely is not set as compression, since I can see in the stats while capturing: `Compression ration 1.0:1`.

I also tried to download `LAME 3.99.5 ACM codec` for Windows 64 Bit and I was able to install it (though it was a bit tricky).

I am on Windows 10 64 Bit. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. After you select LAME codec you also have to select the format. Did you? Note it can only support limited set of sample rates and mono/stereo.
2. There is something weird about compression ratio. Looks like it shows incoming compression (when audio is already compressed by capture source).